# I can't figure out why a class i made isn't working

Tags: java

I just started with objects and classes and when i try to use a method in the class through the .method thing I get a syntax error. I used almost an identical format for a previous practice problem and it worked fine so I'm drawing a blank here.

this is the class for the object.

```
public class Automobile {
    public double mpg;
    public double gallons = 0;

    public Automobile(double mpg) {
        this.mpg = mpg;
    }

    public void fill(double f) {
        gallons += f;
    }

    public void takeTrip(double m) {
        gallons = gallons - (1 / (mpg / m));
    }

    public void reportFuel() {
        System.out.println(gallons);
    }
}
```

this is the tester class

```
public class Tester {
Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
 myBmw.fill(20);
 myBmw.takeTrip(100);
 myBmw.reportFuel();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per java syntax, you can't write executable statements as mentioned here:

```
 myBmw.fill(20);
 myBmw.takeTrip(100);
 myBmw.reportFuel();
```

out of methods/constructors/blocks. You need to move your code to an appropriate place as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You `Tester` class is trying to execute code outside of a valid execution context (ie a `method` or `static` block)...

```
public class Tester {
    Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
    public Tester() {
        myBmw.fill(20);
        myBmw.takeTrip(100);
        myBmw.reportFuel();
    }
}
```

For example...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in the class like this. You have to call other class methods from a method/block.

```
public class Tester {
  Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
  public Tester(){  // It may be any other function 

    myBmw.fill(20);
    myBmw.takeTrip(100);
    myBmw.reportFuel();
  }

  // OR if you miss the main()
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24); 
    myBmw.fill(20);
    myBmw.takeTrip(100);
    myBmw.reportFuel();
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel kind of stupid for forgetting the main, since everything else I've done has that. But now that I'm thinking about it I don't know how main works. is main a built in method for eclipse, or does the fact that its a function just tell the program to compile everything inside.

Comment: @Phil `main()` is the starting point of the program, but it is not the built-in method. It just tell the JVM to start from here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the block

```
public class Tester {
Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
 myBmw.fill(20);
 myBmw.takeTrip(100);
 myBmw.reportFuel();
}
```

to

```
public class Tester {
Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
public Tester(){
 myBmw.fill(20);
 myBmw.takeTrip(100);
 myBmw.reportFuel();
}
}
```

or place it inside another method in Tester class or a static { } block(you will need to declare Automobile instance as static too for this)

Answer (score 0):

You should use main class , I have executed your code and its running fine when we use main class

```
public class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
     myBmw.fill(20);
     myBmw.takeTrip(100);
     myBmw.reportFuel();
}
}
```

And if you dont want to use main() , then you should use a method for it

```
public void testME() {
        Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
        myBmw.fill(20.0);
        myBmw.takeTrip(100);
        myBmw.reportFuel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide main method in your tester class so that you got error.

```
public class Tester {
public static void main(String args[]){ // main method required.
Automobile myBmw = new Automobile(24);
 myBmw.fill(20);
 myBmw.takeTrip(100);
 myBmw.reportFuel();
}
}
```